# Why does my stored procedure return -1?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure. The call to it returns -1. What does this mean?

Here is the code that calls the stored procedure (auto-generated by Entity Framework):

```
public virtual int DeleteProjectData(Nullable<int> projectId, string deleteType, string username)
{
    var projectIdParameter = projectId.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("projectId", projectId) :
                new ObjectParameter("projectId", typeof(int));

    var deleteTypeParameter = deleteType != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("deleteType", deleteType) :
                new ObjectParameter("deleteType", typeof(string));

    var usernameParameter = username != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("username", username) :
                new ObjectParameter("username", typeof(string));

    int result = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("DeleteProjectData", 

projectIdParameter, deleteTypeParameter, usernameParameter);

    return result; // result is -1
}
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteProjectData]
    @projectId INT,
    @deleteType VARCHAR(10),
    @username NVARCHAR(255)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY

    DECLARE @realProjectId      INT = NULL,
            @isTemplate         BIT,
            @ErrorMessage       NVARCHAR(4000),
            @deleteTypeAll      VARCHAR(10),
            @deleteTypeNodes    VARCHAR(10)

    DECLARE @usernameBinary VARBINARY(255)
    SET @usernameBinary = CAST(@username AS VARBINARY(255))
    SET CONTEXT_INFO @usernameBinary

    SELECT @deleteTypeAll = 'All',
           @deleteTypeNodes = 'Nodes'

    -- ensure the input project exists and is not a template
    SELECT @realProjectId = ProjectId
    FROM Project
    WHERE ProjectId = @projectId

    IF @deleteType NOT IN (@deleteTypeAll, @deleteTypeNodes)
        BEGIN
        -- create a the error message for a project that does not exist            
        SELECT @ErrorMessage = N'The input Delete Type is not valid. Valid values are: ''' + @deleteTypeAll 
                                 + ''' and ''' + @deleteTypeNodes + ''''

        -- raise the error
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 16, 1)

        END

    IF @realProjectId IS NULL
        BEGIN
        -- create a the error message for a project that does not exist            
        SELECT @ErrorMessage = N'The input ProjectId does not have a corresponding Project record. No calculations will 

be performed. ProjectId: ' + CAST(@projectId AS VARCHAR)

        -- raise the error
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 16, 1)

        END

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    -- If deleting all, delete all reports associated with project first:
    IF @deleteType = @deleteTypeAll
        BEGIN

        DELETE [dbo].[ReportComment]
        WHERE ReportId in (SELECT ReportId
        FROM [dbo].[Report]
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId)

        DELETE [dbo].[ReportMetric]
        WHERE ReportId in (SELECT ReportId
        FROM [dbo].[Report]
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId)

        DELETE [dbo].[ReportTopN]
        WHERE ReportId in (SELECT ReportId
        FROM [dbo].[Report]
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId)

        DELETE [dbo].[Report]
        WHERE ReportId in (SELECT ReportId
        FROM [dbo].[Report]
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId)

        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN

        DELETE [dbo].[ReportTopN]
        WHERE ReportId in (SELECT ReportId
        FROM [dbo].[Report]
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId)

        END

    IF @deleteType IN (@deleteTypeAll, @deleteTypeNodes)
        BEGIN
        DECLARE @Keys TABLE (
            ProjectId INT,
            NodeId INT,
            DeviationId INT,
            CauseId INT,
            ConsequenceId INT,
            SafeguardId INT,
            RecommendationId INT,
            RemarkId INT,
            DrawingId INT,
            RiskDataId INT,
            BowtieLoopId INT,
            BowtieId INT)

        -- build a list of keys associated with the project (simplifies delete queries)
        INSERT INTO @Keys (ProjectId,
                           NodeId,
                           DeviationId,
                           CauseId,
                           ConsequenceId,
                           SafeguardId,
                           RecommendationId,
                           RemarkId,
                           DrawingId,
                           RiskDataId,
                           BowtieLoopId,
                           BowtieId)
            SELECT p.ProjectId,
                   n.NodeId,
                   d.DeviationId,
                   ca.CauseId,                 
                   co.ConsequenceId,
                   s.SafeguardId,
                   r.RecommendationId,
                   re.RemarkId,
                   dr.DrawingId,
                   rd.RiskDataId,
                   bl.BowtieLoopId,
                   b.BowtieId
            FROM Project p
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Node n
                    ON p.ProjectId = n.ProjectId
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Deviation d
                    ON n.NodeId = d.NodeId
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Cause ca
                    ON d.DeviationId = ca.DeviationId
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Consequence co
                    ON ca.CauseId = co.CauseId
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Safeguard s
                    ON co.ConsequenceId = s.ConsequenceId
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Recommendation r
                    ON co.ConsequenceId = r.ConsequenceId
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Remark re
                    ON co.ConsequenceId = re.ConsequenceId
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Drawing dr
                    ON r.RecommendationId = dr.RecommendationId
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Bowtie b 
                    ON b.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN BowtieLoop bl
                    ON bl.BowtieId = b.BowtieId
                 LEFT Outer JOIN RiskData rd
                    ON rd.BowtieLoopId = bl.BowtieLoopId

            WHERE p.ProjectId = @realProjectId

        -- delete the data that was imported 

        DELETE FROM Drawing
        WHERE DrawingId IN (SELECT DISTINCT DrawingId
                            FROM @Keys)

        DELETE FROM Recommendation
        WHERE RecommendationId IN (SELECT DISTINCT RecommendationId
                                   FROM @Keys)

        DELETE FROM Safeguard
        WHERE SafeguardId IN (SELECT DISTINCT SafeguardId
                              FROM @Keys)

        DELETE FROM Remark
        WHERE RemarkId IN (SELECT DISTINCT RemarkId
                           FROM @Keys)

        DELETE FROM Consequence
        WHERE ConsequenceId IN (SELECT DISTINCT ConsequenceId
                                FROM @Keys)

        DELETE FROM CauseToBowtieLoopDetails
        Where CauseId IN (Select Distinct CauseId 
                          FROM @Keys)

        DELETE FROM Cause
        WHERE CauseId IN (SELECT DISTINCT CauseId
                          FROM @Keys)       

        DELETE FROM Deviation
        WHERE DeviationId IN (SELECT DISTINCT DeviationId
                              FROM @Keys)

        DELETE FROM Node
        WHERE NodeId IN (SELECT DISTINCT NodeId
                         FROM @Keys)

        DELETE FROM RiskData
        WHERE RiskDataId IN (SELECT DISTINCT RiskDataId
                          FROM @Keys)   

        DELETE FROM BowtieLoop
        WHERE BowtieLoopId IN (SELECT DISTINCT BowtieLoopId
                          FROM @Keys)

        DELETE FROM BowtieToEquipmentLookup
        WHERE BowtieId IN (SELECT DISTINCT BowtieId
                            FROM @Keys)

        DELETE FROM Bowtie
        WHERE BowtieId IN (SELECT DISTINCT BowtieId
                          FROM @Keys)   

        DELETE FROM ProjectDeviation
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM ProjectSafeguard
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM ProjectRecommendation
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        -- also delete from the metrics tables

        DELETE FROM ProjectMetrics
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM CauseMetrics
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM ConsequenceMetrics
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM RecommendationMetrics
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM SafeguardMetrics
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId        

        END

    IF @deleteType = @deleteTypeAll
        BEGIN

        -- delete the project specific data (i.e., data not imported)

        DELETE FROM RiskMatrixAxis
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM SafeRecCategory
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM Participant
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM RiskRanking
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM Category
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM ImportFile
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        DELETE FROM Project
        WHERE ProjectId = @realProjectId

        END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        IF(@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
            BEGIN
            -- rollback all changes if any error occurred
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            END

            -- raise the original error
        EXEC RethrowError;
    END CATCH
```

As you can see, the stored procedure doesn't return anything. I'm told that if it doesn't return anything, the Entity Framework call to run the stored procedure will return the number of rows. So what would it mean that it returns -1? Am I right in interpreting -1 as an error?

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON` will make it return -1.

Comment: For test try to disable noncount option to return some value. When SET NOCOUNT is ON, the count is not return but -1.

 Try : SET NOCOUNT OFF

Comment: I think, still looking for the doc on this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Microsoft doc on ExecuteNonQuery ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

Since you are calling a proc, but trying to treat it like a function, I assume that retrieving it's return value results in the same behavior.

Comment: Thank you Barry, I've confirmed that this is the right answer.

Comment: @gib65, mark this as the answer to your question then.